# How to dynamically set component host style Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, binding, components

I want to dynamically set style for child host component element from parent.

There is a solution to do it individually for each style as:

`@HostBinding('style.width') @Input() width = 'auto'`

But this way i need to make multiple lines for different styles.

Bellow is a solution to do this with Host binding and input combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ngStyle` is designated for this.

```html
<app-button [ngStyle]="{ marginTop: '10px', marginLeft: '50px' }">Some button</app-button>
```

Of course, instead of hard coding it into the template like this you could outsource it into the controller.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

PS: Since `style` already exists on all elements I'm not sure of the behavoiur of your code

Comment: Yea, this is a good point.
Maybe use custom host binding makes sense if you want to filter out some styles. As for the behaviour of [styles] attribute, it works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that can cover if you want to pass multiple css styles as string or as object with cammelCase conventions:

**Parent HTML**

```
<app-button [style]="styleFromParent">Some button</app-button>
```

Parent component has `styleFromParent` property and it has simulation if that property is changed at some point:

**Parent Component TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-site-panel',
  templateUrl: './site-panel.component.html',
})
export class SitePanelComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _detectChanges: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
  styleFromParent = { marginTop: '10px', marginLeft: '50px' };

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.styleFromParent = { marginTop: '20px', marginLeft: '1px' };

      this._detectChanges.detectChanges();
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

**Child HTML**

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

**Child Component TS**

In child component part that does parsing if `typeof style === 'object'` is to parse cammelCase styles into dash based styles and concat them into one line string.

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeStyle } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('style') baseStyle: SafeStyle;

  @Input()
  set style(style: string | object) {
    let mappedStyles = style as string;

    if (typeof style === 'object') {
      mappedStyles = Object.entries(style).reduce((styleString, [propName, propValue]) => {
        propName = propName.replace(/([A-Z])/g, matches => `-${matches[0].toLowerCase()}`);
        return `${styleString}${propName}:${propValue};`;
      }, '');

      this.baseStyle = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(mappedStyles);
    } else if (typeof style === 'string') {
      this.baseStyle = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(mappedStyles);
    }
  }

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Above you can see that `baseStyle` has `HostBinding` to `style` component binding.
When `style` input is passed setter will triger, check if string or object is passed, parse it to string and sanitize that css and assign it to `baseStyle` thus host style will change.

**EDIT:**

As @Scorpioo590 said, this is replacable with `[ngStyle]`.
So this seems unneeded. Maybe at least this can show what can you do with style and HostBinding.

Comment: wasnt unneeded for me as  i wanted to set host from child based on component input. awesome to have this!